# A Problem in Pigeonhole Principles.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

> A computer network consists of six computers. Each computer is
>   directly connected to at least one of the other computers. Show that
>   there are at least two computers in the network that are directly
>   connected to the same number of other computers.

I want to solve this problem with pigeonhole principle, but I can't do it.

Please give me a hint or answer.

Comment: If every computer is hooked to a different number of connections and none are hooked up to 0 then there is one computer with 6 or more connections.  But there are only 5 computers for it to be connected to.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. What are the possible number of connections for a computer in the network? How does that compare to the number of computers?

**Edit in response to comment.** Since the very strong hint wasn't enough, here's a solution.

Each of the six computers might be connected to 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 of the others (since 0 is not a possibility). That's just five possible values. Since there are six computers, some value must occur twice. (That's the pigeonhole principle).

Just to test your understanding:

- Does this argument work for a network with $n$ computers, or is six
  special?
- Would the claim have to be true if some computers could be completely disconnected?

Comment: I am thinking about.  .   . But i can't solve the problem .  . .  

Answer (score 0):

Note: the most computers any one computer connect to is 5.  There just aren't any *other* computers to connect to.

So you have 5 possible numbers of connections, and 6 computers so... pigeon hole!